# Fan speed subtly raised

Tags: fan, cpu-cooler

I tried to put a video card (that I didn't know if it was working or not) on my computer, which is really old. The video card didn't work so I unplugged it and went back to use my computer as always. However, when I turned it on, the cooler was a lot louder than before.

I thought it was because some wire or dirt, so I opened it again, cleaned the cooler and checked the wires, but the problem persists. My cooler RPM when idle was about 980 RPM, but now it is about 2200. The noise was really annoying me, so I went to BIOS and set the cooler to "quiet mode", which reduced the RPM and the noise.

However, I'm afraid this can damage my PC in the future, so I would like to know if any of you guys have some idea about how to decrease cooler RPM without using quiet mode on BIOS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the BIOS you should be able to set the fan to have different speeds for different temperatures.  The 'Quiet' setting that you chose probably already has some preset defaults for this, so you should be ok.  One way to tell for sure is to stress test your computer a bit (play a game, run a benchmark, etc) and you should hear the fan get louder as it increases speed relative to the temps.  Keep in mind that since you chose 'Quiet' the fan may not ramp up until the temps get higher than if you chose a different fan preset in the BIOS.